# Pivoting in SQL Server with single Column only

Tags: sql, pivot

I want to make all table column data into select columns like -

If i have

```
ID Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

I have another table in which i have respected values for A, B , C
I want like -

```
A     B    C
NA    2%   NA
1%    NA   6%
NA    NA   NA
1%    4%   8%
```

Please assist.
Thanks 
Abhay

Comment: Please show us this other table. Unclear where the percentage values are derived from.

Comment: I have one table for tax information like 'A', 'B', C...
and having a different table for the values of A, B, C... these values will be different for different cites.



TaxZoneId TaxTypeId Rate
2 3 5%
3 1 6%
4 1 7%
4 2 7%
5 1 8%
5 4 8%
6 1 11%
6 2 12%
7 3 13%
7 4 14%

Comment: Unable to format in tabular view :(